# Use v:content.render in a Contentelement

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I try to render some Elements from another page via fluid in a Partial and try to use `v:content.render`. As you can see in the code I want to render 3 elements from the page with the Uid 9. But as soon as I have the `v:content.render` element in it I just get a blank page.

So my question is how to use `v:content.render` or what alternative I have? Or do I still need to use Typoscript for that?

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
<div class="footer2">

    <v:content.render column="0" limit="3" pageUid="9" as="contentElements">
      <f:for each="{contentElements}" as="contentElement" iteration="footerIteration">
        <f:format.html>{contentElement.bodytext}</f:format.html>
      </f:for>
    </v:content.render>

</div>
```

I am not sure if it is important, but the elements on the Page 9 are also fluid content elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that works:

```
<v:variable.set name="contentElements" value="{v:content.get(column:'0', limit:'3', pageUid:'9',  render:'FALSE')}" />

  <f:for each="{contentElements}" as="contentElement" iteration="footerIteration">
    <v:content.render contentUids="{0:contentElement.uid}" />
    <f:format.html>{contentElement.bodytext}</f:format.html>
  </f:for>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your first attempt was more readable. `{contentElement}` already had what you needed, there is no property `bodytext` if you leave `render` to its default `true`.

```
<v:content.render column="0" pageUid="9" limit:"3" as="contentElements">
    <f:for each="{contentElements}" as="contentElement">
        <f:format.raw>{contentElement}</f:format.raw>
    </f:for>
</v:content.render>
```

If you don't know what you get back in `as=""` to work with, just try a debug:

```
<v:content.render column="0" pageUid="9" limit:"3" as="contentElements">
    <f:for each="{contentElements}" as="contentElement">
        <f:debug inline="true">{contentElement}</f:debug>
    </f:for>
</v:content.render>
```

And I replaced `<f:format.html>` with `<f:format.raw>` so prevent some unwanted `<p></p>`